# Unable to get docs and facets in one solr CQL query in DSE Search

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, cql3

**Requirement:** Is to implement faceted search using **DSE Search**

**Problem:** Unable to get docs or data and **facets** in one CQL solr query.

**Tools & Technology Used:** Datastax Sandbox 5.1 (Cent OS + Virtual box) and trying DSE search

Created following table & used dsetool enable solr (**DSE Search**):

```
CREATE TABLE test.employee_copy1 (
    empid int,
    deptid int,
    name text,
    solr_query text, -- column got created by enabling DSE Search
    PRIMARY KEY (empid, deptid)
)
```

Inserted following data,

```
INSERT INTO employee (empid,deptid,name) VALUES (100,200,'John');
INSERT INTO employee (empid,deptid,name) VALUES (101,201,'Helen');
INSERT INTO employee (empid,deptid,name) VALUES (102,201,'John');
```

I tried facet query from Solr Admin as below

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test.employee/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=name
```

Got the results containing both docs ( or data) and facets as expected,

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 3,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
                "_uniqueKey": "[\"100\",\"200\"]",
                "empid": 100,
                "deptid": 200,
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "_uniqueKey": "[\"101\",\"201\"]",
                "empid": 101,
                "deptid": 201,
                "name": "Helen"
            },
            {
                "_uniqueKey": "[\"102\",\"201\"]",
                "empid": 102,
                "deptid": 201,
                "name": "John"
            }
        ]
    },
    "facet_counts": {
        "facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {
            "name": [
                "john", 2,
                "helen", 1
            ]
        },
        "facet_dates": {},
        "facet_ranges": {},
        "facet_intervals": {}
    }
}
```

**But when tried the following query (CQL) in Datastax devcenter expecting to see data and facets, I see only facets**

```
select JSON * from test.employee where solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet" : {"field":"name"}}';
```

Got the result but it has only facets and not data:

```
{"facet_fields" : {"name" : {"john" : 2,"helen" : 1 } } }
```

**Question:** Can anyone explain why CQL query doesn't return data in-spite of specifying `"q":"*:*"`?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with the HTTP query interface, it is [not possible](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/queriesJSON.html#queriesJSON__solrFacetquery) to get both row results and facets from a single CQL `solr_query` in DSE 5.1 (or any earlier versions).

Comment: Thanks. You have mentioned its not possible in DSE 5.1, is there any other version that supports getting both docs and facets?

Also, can you please point me or educate me on what is the technical reason behind this limitation?

Comment: I've updated my response to clarify that there is no version of DSE that supports this, as of 5.1.

Comment: It's not technically impossible to do this, but one concern here is the awkwardness of placing both facet results and document results in a single row-based result with the same column headings.

Comment: I have an application, I want to perform the query and get facets for subsequent interactions. Because I cannot get the docs and facets in one call, I need to make 2 calls to Cassandra/DSE. 

Atleast, the query having 'SELECT * JSON ...' should return both to make sure we have a feature similar to what we have in Solr http API.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a product decision. As Caleb pointed out, the developer experience with parsing the result was seen as less than desirable. Further more, with a distributed, P2P datastore (C*), the workaround of issuing 2 async queries, 1 for the facet result and 1 for the "Top Ten" is the preferred query pattern. They do not have to be done serially.

Ultimately, if the Solr behavior is desired, than the Solr HTTP API is available to use in DSE. The CQL API is aimed more at providing simple FTS on the C* data, not necessarily supporting or doing everything vanilla Solr does through CQL.

Comment: What you say about having 2 async queries one for docs/data and one for facets makes sense. We can do that. But there are scenarios where we may want to avoid two calls across various layers or network and NRI setup.
In our company we have C* (DSE Enterprise) + Solr (DSE Search) setup. Data written to C* gets indexed in Solr (multiple C* nodes). You have mentioned that we can use Solr HTTP API, If I directly use Solr HTTP API, will I get all the data available across multiple C* cluster?